# Integration by Parts on $\sqrt{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have been asked to show that $$\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}dx$$

I'm aware of how to do this with trig substitution, but the question is specifically regarding integration by parts, and the only examples I can find keep using trig subs.

So far I have integrated twice. The first time was with $u=\sqrt{1+x^2},v'=1$. Resulting in the following:

$$\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$

The first term is almost correct. Integrating this new integral, with $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}, v'=1$. Gave me the following:

$$\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$

From here I'm pretty much stuck. I can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to get rid of the middle term. The final integral can be put into the right form if I divide by $x$, but then the first term loses it's $x$ scalar and I still can't drop the middle term.

I feel as though I've made a mistake on one of the integrations, but I've been looking over it for that long that the whole thing is blurry.

Comment: Your first integration by parts is wrong. Double check.

Comment: Yeah I just caught that after reading the answer below.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar. It's from a math course I'm taking currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with integration by parts
$$v=x, \ dv=dx$$
$$u=\sqrt{1+x^2}, \ du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}\int \sqrt{1+x^2}dx&=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx \\
&=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\frac{(1+x^2)-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\\
&=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
&=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx+\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx.\end{align*}
Just add $\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx$ to both sides. This means that
$$2\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
or
$$\int\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=\frac12x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\frac12\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

Comment: So I only needed to do IbP once, and then just manipulate it afterwards?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Alright then. Out of curiousity would I still be able to get to the same answer by doing it twice? Even though it isn't necessary since your answer is much simpler to follow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. How would you propose to choose $u$ and $v$ for the second integration by parts?

Comment: Similar to what I wrote in the original question, but accounting for my mistake in the first IbP result. So you would have $v'=1$ and $u=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method, but not really so different from the other answer:
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx
&=
\int\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx
\\[6px]
&=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx+
\int x\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx 
\qquad \biggl(u=x, v'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\biggr)
\\[6px]
&=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx+x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
2\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx
=
x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx
$$