# Vinyl Record Arc Length

Tags: polar-coordinates

Right now the I am using this formula to calculate the arc length:

$$L=\int_a^b\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$

The grooves on the vinyl replicate an Archimedean spiral given in the form of $r= \lambda θ$, where $\lambda $ is a constant. I am having trouble determining the exact number of complete turns and what the value for spacing between each turn should be. Currently, the vinyl record I am using is $754~\text{s}$ long and is played at $40~\text{rpm}$ .
Can someone help me formulate an equation? I am not quite sure where to go from here?

Comment: See example 1 on this [Paul’s Notes article](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/polararclength.aspx). You have a lot of good text, but be sure to learn this essential [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Welcome to MSE!

Comment: It is a recipe for confusion to use the same variable $r$ to mean two different things. It would be clearer if you described your spiral as $r=k \theta$

Comment: If it matters, using calculus here is overkill: The "average radius" of the groove is about $\frac{1}{2}(15.24+7.12) = 11.18$ cm, so the approximate length of the groove is $$2\pi \times 11.18 \times 735 \approx 51630.82\text{ cm.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just have to integrate the arc length of an Archimedian spiral. Let
$$r(\theta)=\lambda\theta$$
So,
$$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}=\lambda$$
So we just have to determine
$$L(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\lambda\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\sqrt{1+\theta^2}~\mathrm d\theta$$

So we need to find an antiderivative for the function $x\mapsto \sqrt{1+x^2}$. We can [use a nice trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814581/integration-by-parts-on-sqrt1x2dx?noredirect=1) to evaluate this as
$$L(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\frac{\lambda}{2}\left(\theta_2\sqrt{1+{\theta_2}^2}+\operatorname{arcsinh} \theta_2\right)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\left(\theta_1\sqrt{1+{\theta_1}^2}+\operatorname{arcsinh} \theta_1\right)$$

Now, you want to measure the spacing of the groove. I'll leave it as an easy exercise to determine that we can relate $\lambda$ to the spacing $s$ by
$$\lambda=\frac{s}{2\pi}$$
We first determine what our $\theta_1$ is. To make things easier, we'll actually imagine the record spinning the other way, with the tonearm going out instead of in. *Assuming the tonearm started right at the center of the record*, the number of turns it would need to make before it got to our starting length of $7.12~\text{cm}$ is just $7.12/s$. So,
$$\theta_1=2\pi\cdot \frac{7.12}{s}=\frac{7.12}{\lambda}$$
Similarly
$$\theta_2=\frac{15.24}{\lambda}$$
So now all that's left is to compute is
$$L\left(\frac{7.12}{\lambda},\frac{15.24}{\lambda}\right)$$
So now what **you** need to do is measure the spacing $s$ and compute $\lambda$.

### **EDIT:**

Rereading the question I remembered that we figured out that it was computed that the record takes $735$ turns. In that case, we can easily solve for $\lambda$ in
$$\frac{15.24-7.12}{\lambda}=2\pi\cdot 735$$
To get
$$\lambda=0.00175828318082$$
Hence
$$L\left(\frac{7.12}{\lambda},\frac{15.24}{\lambda}\right)=51630.8192937~\text{cm}$$
Computed [on Desmos.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ck8ao3ahrs)

Comment: In hindsight, simply starting further out with say $r(\theta)=\lambda \theta+r_0$ is probably easier, but I think either method should work

Comment: @JumpPratumsuwan Yes. Although the length of the rotations changes, the time it takes for a complete rotation does not, since the record player doesn't speed up or slow down. What I mean is that the *tangential* velocity of the pin is increasing whereas the *angular* velocity is not.

Comment: @JumpPratumsuwan Recall again the polar equation $r(\theta)=\lambda \theta$. After a full revolution, we have increased $\theta$ by $2\pi$. So, $r(\theta+2\pi)=\lambda\theta +2\pi\lambda=r(\theta)+s$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tonearm starts and ends at the same angle we have the following system of equations:
$$r = k \theta + r_0 \qquad \begin{cases} 7.12 = k\cdot 0 + r_0 \\
15.24 = k \cdot 735 \cdot 2\pi + r_0 \end{cases} \quad \to \; k = \frac{29}{5250 \pi}$$
$$\int_0^{735\cdot 2\pi} \sqrt{(k\theta+r_0)^2+k^2} \text{ d}\theta \approx 51630.8 \text{ cm}$$